# Validation mvc submit button enabled only when valid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm using DataAnnotations on my models and the JavaScript validation is working fine, but I now need to disable the submit button when the validation is invalid

Here is some sample code that I am trying to get working

```
<h2>
Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>HomeModel</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" id="submit-button" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")</div>@section Scripts {    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")}
```

Comment: I require help on this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225962/jquery-form-disable-submit-button-until-required-field-entered

Answer (score -1):

you can use :

```
$("#myform").validate({
  success: function() {
    //here enable your button
  }
});
```